# why does my function .show of jquery doesnt work on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

i have a button that is supossed to show a hidden div tag when pressed, it is not working though and i am not sure why. here is my html code:

```
<div class="cambio-imagen">
    <form id="form-cambio-imagen" action="usuario/imagechange/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
        <input type="file" name="us_picture" id="id_us_picture">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="cambiar" />
    </form>
</div>
```

and my javascript:

```
<script>
  function doIt() {
      $(".cambio-imagen").show("slow");
  }
  $("#boton-imagen").click(doIt);
  $("#form-cambio-imagen").submit(function (event) {
      $(".cambio-imagen").hide("fast");
  });
  }
  });
</script>
```

import

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

can someone help me out? im new to jquery and javascript. thanks.

Comment: the function doIt() is not called anywhere

Comment: Where the doIt() is called?

Comment: you have syntax errors

Comment: I edited your question to apply appropriate indentation to your JS (no change other than whitespace) - you'll notice now that it is obvious that you have an extra `}` and `});` on the last two lines of your script, syntax errors that prevent the whole thing from working. (Even aside from the issue of whether you need a document ready handler or not.) @Praveen and Marikkani - `doIt()` is bound as a click handler, but other syntax errors prevent the script working.

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors, and add the script in dom ready hadnler

```
jQuery(function () {
    function doIt() {
        $(".cambio-imagen").show("slow");
    }
    $("#boton-imagen").click(doIt);
    $("#form-cambio-imagen").submit(function (event) {
        $(".cambio-imagen").hide("fast");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Errors in your script call Document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function doIt() {
        $(".cambio-imagen").show("slow");
    }
    $("#boton-imagen").click(doIt);
    $("#form-cambio-imagen").submit(function (event) {
        $(".cambio-imagen").hide("fast");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use jquery toggle method. You can able to achieve your requirements.

Check this URL : http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: What about fixing the syntax errors in the OP's script? Why wouldn't `.show()` work?

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$("#boton-imagen").click(function(){
    doIt();
});
```

And you have syntax errors too..Try like

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#boton-imagen").click(function(){
          $(".cambio-imagen").show("slow");
       });
       $("#form-cambio-imagen").submit(function (event) {
           $(".cambio-imagen").hide("fast");
       });    
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Why? `$("#boton-imagen").click(doIt);` is valid. (What about fixing the actual syntax errors?)

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```
function doIt() {
      $(".cambio-imagen").show("slow");
}

$("#boton-imagen").click(
    doIt();
);

$("#form-cambio-imagen").submit(function (event) {
      $(".cambio-imagen").hide("fast");
  });
```

Comment: Why add an anonymous function to wrap the call to `doIt()`? The OP's version with `$("#boton-imagen").click(doIt);` is valid.

Comment: You have to Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event

Comment: Yes, and `$("#boton-imagen").click(doIt);` binds `doIt()`. You have the option of using an anonymous function, but you don't have to (and there's no point when all it does is call the other function that you could've bound directly).

Comment: you have to use doIt(); instead of doIt

Comment: No. With parentheses it calls the function immediately. Without parentheses you get a reference to the function that can be bound. See for yourself here: http://jsfiddle.net/zSPLa/